# High CPU load while browsing (AMD A6)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, cpu-usage

My CPU is AMD A6-9220 RADEON R4.
I use Ubuntu 16.04.1. No additional (proprietary) drivers available.
CPU loads both in Chrome and Firefox, hardware acceleration is off in Chrome. 
It happens when I scroll page mostly.
Or when browser open and I do something else (run some other tasks).

Using top command I've found out that Xorg process eats about 50%.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound I added version of Ubuntu and exact model of CPU, something else ?

Comment: It's the lack of optimization of the driver to the application code. In this case a very basic CPU commands are used when accessing CPU resources shared with other apps/OS (accessing cache, TLB, other buffers used when running application code).

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the following command during high load and find out which process is causing it:

   ```
   top
   ```
2. Then you can use ps or ptree commands for the process to drill down further.